# where i should properly store first password

Tags: spring-security

I have a question about storing "base" password for spring security app. I read documentation and IMHO i should have first pass stored somewhere hardcoded. Is that right or how i should be done?
As example i've post defauld helloWorld code from spring security.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();

        String s = encoder.encode("password");
        UserDetails user = User.withUsername("userName")
                .password(s)
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options.

1. Hardcode it.
2. Store username/pass in a .property file. This gives you more flexibility, and also an ability to disable the user (e.g. set the name to empty and skipping it in the code)
3. Generate password via existing `PasswordGenerator` and add login/pass manually to a DB via SQL. This way you have even more flexibility, you can have as many initial users as you want (and you can always delete them), and also this approach can guarantee that logins will be unique (you need some special handling in your code to check, that the login of any new user doesn't match the login of the first user).